# How to configure Azure Pipelines to run only on commits to the master branch and after pull requests are merged?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a GitHub repository that triggers Azure Pipelines. I want to configure the pipeline to run only when there are commits pushed to the `master` branch, and not on any other branch.

If there are pull requests againt `master`, I want to ensure that the pipeline only runs after pull requests are merged into the master branch and not before the pull request is merged.

So far I have created the Azure Pipeline YAML file below. It fulfills the requirements

- execute on commits to `master`
- do not execute on commits to other branches

However if I have a differently named branch and create a pull request against `master`, then this pieline is triggered as well.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master

resources:
  - repo: self

variables:
  - name: imageName
    value: sample
  - group: containerReg

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build image
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          # Build the container image
          - task: Docker@2
            inputs:
              containerRegistry: 'GHCR service connection'
              repository: '$(registryUsername)/$(imageName)'
              command: 'build'
              Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
              tags: |
                $(Build.BuildId)
                latest
            displayName: Build and tag container image

          # Login to containter registry
          - task: Docker@2
            inputs:
              containerRegistry: 'GHCR service connection'
              command: 'login'
            displayName: Login to container registry

          # Push all tagged images to the container registry
          - task: Docker@2
            inputs:
              containerRegistry: 'GHCR service connection'
              repository: '$(registryUsername)/$(imageName)'
              command: 'push'
              tags: |
                $(Build.BuildId)
                latest
            displayName: Push all tagged images to the container registry
```

What is the best way to configure the Azure Pipeline YAML file to achieve this?
I know that I can define conditions for stages, jobs, and step, but I want the entire pipeline to prevent from running.

Comment: You are looking for this pr: none https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pr?view=azure-pipelines

Comment: @JTIM You are right, this is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! Don't know why I was too blind to reveal this myself. Please submit this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @JTIM `pr` only applies to BitBucket and GitHub repos, not Azure DevOps.

Comment: @DanielMann we agree the questions is about GitHub right? I do not get your comment?

Comment: @JTIM You're right, I must've missed the 4th word of the post... somehow. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For repositories hosted in GitHub or bitbucket it is possible to use `pr: none`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pr?view=azure-pipelines